# Wireless adapter connects every time I insert it, but stops working after a short while

Tags: 12.04, wireless

The model is Edimax EW-7811UN 150Mbps Wireless Nano USB Adapter.

It doesn't work for more than a few minutes, but if I take it out and let it cool then insert it again, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with a Dell D1450U USB wireless card. The problem was almost certainly with software at some level and not hardware.

It may be faster to get back online - if you look under the menu for network settings

1. Enable wireless (wait for the check-mark to go away)
2. then re-enable and connect (if not done automatically)

You may be better off posting in the Ubuntu Networking & Wireless forums where people can tell you what specific information could help diagnose the problem (ex. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1818988).

Good luck!

Comment: I will post in there too, thank you for directing me. I would do the re-enabling thing, but I would like a solution that doesn't imply having to do something every few minutes. It sounds easier than re-inserting the adapter though.